# Android Studio Network Profiler Retrofit 2- Network Profiling Data Unavailable

Tags: android-studio, retrofit2, android-profiler

I'm running into an issue with the Android Studio Network Profiler. I can't see any of the network requests for my application. I'm currently using Retrofit 2. It seems the Profiler was built to work with OKHttp.

From my understanding Retrofit is built on top of OKHttp, so I'm not sure if there's something I'm missing to see the log data.

Version:

```
com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that Retrofit will log in the Android Profiler. Unfortunately, in my case, the app was crashing during an initial network call. Despite launching the app in debug mode even with the debugger attached, it seems Android Studio didn't have enough time to fully initialize the Profiler and log any data.